# See entire preview while editing a question

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits

Most editing doesn't take a tremendous amount of time especially when it's in a tag you are familiar with. New users typically don't use backticks properly or will leave logcat and other error messages unformatted. You go in and fix these things along with some grammar, spelling, and other formatting (maybe even adjust the title or tags). Fine.

However, sometimes a post is unusually long (and maybe even unnecessarily so) and the formatting is all throughout the post. If a user posts, say, 3 or 4 classes and each one has some elements out of the code block or needs edited in some other way then you need to edit one class at a time...scrolling down on the main page each time to figure out if you got all of that class and where the next one starts.

**Solution?**

Could the preview window pop out maybe next to the window where you edit. They each could scroll dependently of the other. If this could somehow work, at least on long posts where scrolling is necessary, then it would speed up the time of doing long edits.

Another bonus from this would be that it might cut down on more minor edits being approved while trying to take the time and make a more "correct" and effective edit.

Now, I do understand that posts that long can typically have the code cut down but I don't like to do that until it's been edited to see what is what and leave some comments for the OP to see what code is actually necessary.

**Drawbacks**

None...I don't have to build it.

[Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25881010/error-parsing-data-org-json-jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-c) of a post where I needed to do a lot of scrolling to see the bottom of the post to find out if I was done...then scroll back up.

Something like this...

[image]

and they could both scroll together in harmony. And as [Air pointed out in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269346/see-entire-preview-while-editing-a-question#comment82500_269346) this could work for posting new questions and answers as well.

Comment: @derp that's what I was thinking in my head, " maybe next to the window where you edit" but maybe I wasn't clear.

Comment: *None...I don't have to build it.*

Comment: @derp I don't see those sidebars but, yes, side-by-side is what I was going for.

Comment: It would be a great help to have pop-out and/or side-by-side preview when first composing a post as well. Scrolling two windows along the same axis when one is nested in the other can be very awkward.

Comment: Well, it's non-trivial figuring out how to synchronize scrolling...

Comment: @codeMagic  I have a [Side By Side Editing](http://stackapps.com/q/6461/26088) userscript on Stack Apps if you would like side-by-side editing :) That is also in my [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) userscript :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I will check that out. Thanks! But I still think SO should build this in if possible

Comment: @codeMagic definitely! There are already many feature requests on meta for it!

Comment: Please consider this one!  https://discuss.elastic.co does a real nice full screen side by side editor.  I believe improving the experience of writing questions will improve the quality of the questions!