# Synchronize edit and preview views while editing

Tags: feature-request, editor

I usually wrote a bit longer **Q/A** and often make formatting errors because I simply do not see The right part of body in preview while editing.

[image: actual state]

As you can see while editing bullet **#4** I see only bullets **#1,#2** in preview. This is very discomfort-able (at least for me for a long time). I think this can be remedied by:

1. **synchronizing the preview position to that in editor**

   But this may be tricky due to mark down formatted preview is very different from the source text.
2. **adding (separate) scrollbar to preview**

   This is a bit less comfortable solution then **#1** because the views are not synchronized automatically but should be **much much simpler/safer** to implement while still providing desired functionality. I think something like this:

   [image: preview scroll bar]

**[edit1] just found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269346/2521214) related (almost duplicate) question**

Weird that it was not showed in any of mine earlier searches for this but here in related column it is ...