# Do suggested duplicate links ever disappear for the OP when there are close votes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

So I asked [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341489/would-a-side-by-side-option-for-viewing-the-question-while-answering-be-useful), someone got the wrong end of the stick and it got a few duplicate close votes, at which point I as the OP start to see this dialog:

[image]

I checked it and saw that it was incorrectly flagged, as the duplicate wasn't the same request so I acknowledged the dialog and attempted to dismiss it.

However, it doesn't disappear and it's quite annoying that it still shows up after I've checked and acknowledged. I'm aware this is network wide behaviour and it's probably useful in some cases, but I was wondering what if anything can be done?

Do I have to wait for the close votes to be retracted or time away? Would it disappear then when I'm grey(er) and old(er)? Or could I go to the extreme of flagging the incorrect close votes to a mod to check and remove? Don't really want to do that and I'm not sure a mod would do that either, so thought I'd ask here instead for now.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait till the votes age away or the close voters retract their vote. An alternative is to close vote it and then re-open but for an annoyance only seen by you that is a bit too much effort. Do know it survived the [Close Vote queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/13119). That doesn't happen often ...

Comment: There are actually still two close votes on that question from users with full close-vote privileges, so no, the message isn't going to go away until those users either retract their close-votes manually, or they age away automatically.

Comment: Yeah I expected as much

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that the notice doesn't show a 'No, let met [edit] to explain why this question is different' option. Is that only for <3k users?

Comment: @Glorfindel it did show a message along those lines and I did edit the post to explain why it wasn't a duplicate and commented as such, that's what the dialog looks like after I acknowledged and edited.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched harder, found a dupe target.