# Put preview to the right from question/answer input

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-experience

At least for the past 10 years, a typical programmer's monitor had a display with a 16:9 ratio. But most part of the space on the screen on SE sites isn't used properly. It is vertically organized site. Usually, space is blank or filled with something unrelated (especially if I write an answer). Here is a screenshot demonstrating what I usually see on my monitor:

[image]

At the same time, I often write long answers or edit someone's long question or answer. In this case, I always need to scroll forth and back many times to see, if the text looks fine or not. It would be really helpful to see a preview on the same screen, to the right from the input field, for example:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See entire preview while editing a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269346/see-entire-preview-while-editing-a-question), or at least any of its [linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/269346/) questions.

Comment: Yes, it almost the same. But there is no answer. What is the status of that request? Declined? Postponed and nobody knows for how long?

Comment: A feature request doesn’t need to be resolved in order for it to be a duplicate target. We don’t need countless feature requests on the same issue, just because they haven’t been implemented yet.